# Decompose to even and odd functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose we have the function $f(x) = |x-1|$. I have to find the even and odd parts of the function and write them in terms of Heaviside Function. I have no idea what should I do here? I tried and it gave me like 4 equations which I think is not correct.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\frac12(f(x)+f(-x))+\frac12(f(x)-f(-x))$$

Comment: but how can I separate it into a piecewise defined function?

Comment: The first function is 
$$\frac12(|x-1|+|x+1|)$$
and recall that $|x|=x$ if $x\ge0$ and $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$ so in your case you should consider the intervals $(-\infty,-1],[-1,1]$ and $[1,+\infty)$